# Undefined reference to timeGetTime() in g++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using g++ command line under Windows 10 to build a basic timing loop and am getting the error: " undefined reference to `timeGetTime@0' " when attempting to compile.

The code, itself, is pretty simple:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   int start = timeGetTime();
   int finish = 10000;
   int benchmarks [9] = {1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000};
   int i = 0;
   int time = timeGetTime() - start;
   while( time < finish){
       if(time > benchmarks[i]){
           cout << benchmarks[i] / 1000 << endl;
           i++;
       }

   return 0;
}
```

Not sure what I need to do to get g++ to play nicely with the WinAPI. I can't help but wonder if it's an issue with the linker.

Comment: as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629(v=vs.85).aspx you need to reference winmm.lib

Comment: timeGetTime is a very poor function for measuring time for benchmarks.

Comment: I'm not using it for benchmarks. I'm using it as a control function for peripherals which need to be activated according to a particular schedule.

I just called the variable 'benchmarks' as a way of establishing points where I wanted responses. This is largely an early debug before I pass in the more detailed instructions

Answer (score 1):

You have to link libwinmm.

Undefined reference is an error which occures when your compiler knows that the function exist, it knows its prototype, but can't find its corpse. When it is not one of your functions, it surely means you miss to link a library.